# Moving SharePoint 2016 wiki content onto SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016, wiki, onenote

Our SharePoint 2016 site (on-premise or whatever the parlance is) is being migrated to SharePoint Online. **My existing wiki can't be moved (for whatever reason) and I'm trying to figure out a nice way to move the content.**

I was told to cut and paste the content from each wiki page into OneNote, however this doesn't work at all. Unlike copying from a normal web page where the links, and most of the basic formatting, etc. is successfully translated across.

**Can someone advise where I might find where the actual wiki textual content is stored?** I've come across some .aspx files with relevant wiki page names but they're all the same file without the actual content.

In my total ignorance, is the wiki content stored in a DB? If so, where?

Also, it seems the Teams wiki app is being removed by MS in January 2024. Is that the same death knell for wikis in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/692234/sharepoint-wiki-pages-migration

Yes but unfortunately, inaccessible. Use `Content and Structure` to copy them into a normal library, so you can successfully migrate the library containing these wiki pages to SharePoint Online.

Try this and let me know if it helps.